# How to select entries from multiple tables, some of the with count?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hi there! I'm having trouble with the following:

```
return DB::table('companies')
 ->leftJoin('invoice_settings', 'companies.id', '=', 'invoice_settings.company_id')
 ->leftJoin('invoices', 'companies.id', '=', 'invoices.company_id')
 ->leftJoin('estimates', 'companies.id', '=', 'estimates.company_id')
 ->leftJoin('products', 'companies.id', '=', 'products.company_id')
 ->select('companies.id',
 'companies.company_name',
 'companies.company_email',
 'companies.last_login',
 'invoice_settings.depa_vat_registered',
 DB::raw('count(invoices.id) AS total_invoices_generated'),
 DB::raw('count(estimates.id) AS total_estimates_generated'),
 DB::raw('count(products.id) AS total_products_generated'),
 )
 ->groupBy('companies.id')
 ->get();
```

I am getting wrong results when compared to the db record. I need to add several more leftJoins and I was wondering if leftJoin or DB:raw('count.....') is wrong?

In dd I'm getting:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3627 ▼
  #items: array:118 [▼
    0 => {#3631 ▶}
    1 => {#3630 ▶}
    2 => {#3636 ▶}
    3 => {#3629 ▼
      +"id": 141
      +"company_name": "Some company Ltd"
      +"company_email": "mail@gmail.com"
      +"last_login": "2020-08-11 11:46:51"
      +"depa_vat_registered": "no"
      +"total_invoices_generated": 6
      +"total_estimates_generated": 0
      +"total_products_generated": 6
      +"total_credit_notes_generated": 0
```

When I look at the table the above result should be:

```
+"total_invoices_generated": 3
+"total_estimates_generated": 0
+"total_products_generated": 0
+"total_credit_notes_generated": 2
```

And that applies to all records.

Comment: I've removed the `jquery` tag since I believe you were looking for a `query` tag

Comment: Try with distinct `count(distinct invoices.id) `

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Suggestion if you have setup your relations between your model then you don;t have to write this whole query you can just use `withCount` helper with your main model

Comment: Thanks, I'm using it for simple Excel export with https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel